# how to normalize data

Tags: sorting, normalization, ranking

First off I need to start by saying I don't have any code yet for this...

I'm trying to find a way to normalize a data set. 
I have a list of employees who are given a rated of 1 to 5 by X number of persons taking a survey ( X is never constant )

I want the best way to then sort them the best way possible and set a weight factor to it.
(i.e if someone receives a rating of 5(best) but they only have one survey taken on them, they shouldn't necessarily be sorted higher than someone who has a rating of 4 and 20 surveys have been taken about that employee)...

Does anyone have any thoughts? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know, this is really a [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) problem.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.evanmiller.org/ranking-items-with-star-ratings.html

Comment: The headline is absolutely misleading - could you please correct? You do not want a "how to normalize", you want a "how to optimize sorting".